# Build Qt project for arm64 from command line

Tags: android, qt, clang, qt5, qmake

I want to create a script that installs `Qt`, the `Android NDK`, clones a project and builds it.
I used [qli-installer](https://lnj.gitlab.io/post/qli-installer/) to install `Qt 5.13.0` using:

```
./qli-installer.py 5.13.0 linux android android_arm64_v8a
```

which installed `Qt` to `/home/user/5.13.0/`. I downloaded the `Android SDK`(this is not needed yet but I downloaded it anyways...) and `Android NDK` and setup `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19-linux-x86_64.zip
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
mkdir android
cd android
unzip ../sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -d ./sdk/
unzip ../android-ndk-r19-linux-x86_64.zip -d ./ndk/
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/user/android/ndk/android-ndk-r19
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
```

and then I wanted to build the project from `~/project` to `~/project_build/`:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/project_build$ echo $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT 
/home/user/android/ndk/android-ndk-r19/
user@user-VirtualBox:~/project_build$ /home/user/5.13.0/android_arm64_v8a/bin/qmake -spec /home/user/5.13.0/android_arm64_v8a/mkspecs/android-clang/ /home/user/project/project.pro 
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler '/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt//bin/clang++'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
user@user-VirtualBox:~/project_build$
```

Does anyone know what else should I do to setup the environment?

Comment: check out this : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was I installed `Qt` with GUI in `~/Qt`, archived the folder and uploaded it to an internal server. When I needed it on a server without X, I would just `wget` and `unzip` it.

Couldn't find another solution, but this workaround, unfortunately...